# What is the lisp equivalent of javascript's spread operator?

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

Say I wanted to find the highest square of a bunch of numbers:

```
(max (map (lambda (x) (* x x)) (range -4 1))) ; I want 16
```

This doesn't work: `max` expects to be called like `(max 16 9 4 1 0)` and I'm calling it like `(max '(16 9 4 1 0))`.

The operation I want to apply here is the same as Python's asterisk or Javascript's spread operator, but it's neither quoting, unquoting or quasi-quoting...

What is it called in lisp (or Scheme) (or Racket) and how do I perform it? This seems like such a basic operation I'm struggling to find appropriate search terms on Google.

So far the best I've got is a really sad

```
(argmax (lambda (x) x) (map (lambda (x) (* x x)) (range -4 1))) ; 16 but really sadly so
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unroll / splat arguments in common lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345999/unroll-splat-arguments-in-common-lisp) and [Can Scheme expand a list as arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035725/can-scheme-expand-a-list-as-arguments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript rest syntax was included in ECMA2015 / ES6 and before 2015 you had this syntax:

```js
Math.max.apply(
  null,
  [-4, -3, -2, 1].map(function (v) {return v*v; }),
);
// ==> 16
```

And Scheme had it already in the 70s:

```scm
(apply max 
       (map (lambda (v) 
              (* v v)) 
       '(-4 -3 -2 1)))
; ==> 16
```

Note that JS `apply` is less powerful than that of Scheme / Common Lisp. Eg. you could add extra arguments which JS does not support:

```scm
(apply map list '((1 2 3) (a b c)))
; ==> ((1 a) (2 b) (3 c))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `apply` to spread a list into arguments.

```
(apply max (map (lambda (x) (* x x)) (range -4 1)))
```